# Как запустить функцию через dataset?

Tags: javascript, dom

Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот есть строка из HTML  `<button data-proBut="emailPro">Кнопка</button>`
Я получаю через event.target.dataset.probut = **"emailPro"** и хочу запустить его в виде функции в JS,
через **addEventListener** **emailPro()** .Но у меня не выходит:( Запускается через метод **eval()**, но для меня это не совсем выход. Думаю, что контекст просто ссылается на DOM страницу из-за этого и не запускается. Но до победы дойти не получается.
Вот тестовый кусочек кода.

```html
function Menu(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    function emailPro() {
      console.log("asdasda");
    }
    let a = e.target.dataset.probut;

    
  });
}

new Menu(formaPro);
```

Comment: Для чего вам это понадобилось?

Comment: Не для чего, просто в классовом исполнении с привязкой контекста через bind все работает, а вот вне класса, увы(

Answer (score 2):

Наглядный пример как из строкового имени функции вызвать её:

```js
let functionName = 'test';

function test() {
    alert('hello');
}

let func = new Function(`${functionName}()`);
func();
```

Comment: Да, но так в схожем понятии работает и eval(). Я думаю есть возможность запускать такие функции через привязку контекста на объект или метод в который передается DOM. В классовом исполнении видел такие кейсы и они достаточно просты. А вот в функциональном исполнении сложно(